# How to show categories and regarded node in drupal 7

Tags: 7, views

[image]

I have a site in Drupal 7. I am using brands(taxonomy term) and product(node).
For example I have 4 brand -- brand1 brand2 etc.. I need to show all 4 brands and regarding node .. When I click on brand 1 . then brand1 related node need to show..

I need something like this structure..
 display all terms on left and right all regarding products.

Comment: When you say "brands and regarded node", I think you mean something like "brands and all nodes that are tagged with the selected taxonomy term of the brands vocabulary". Do I understand (interpret) your question correctly?

Answer (score 1):

1. Create taxonomy(first add vocabulary and then add terms) by going to
   the below path:

> admin/structure/taxonomy

2. Configure your content type to add a field of type 'term reference':

> admin/structure/types/manage/article/fields

3. Add content and select your brand field.
4. Create a view by doing the following configurations shown in
   attached image.

[image]

Comment: I need to add some fileds not shown all fields... 
I need to create view page or view block?

Comment: Please answer if it is possible by you!!

Comment: Change FORMAT settings of views as shown above in screen shot and choose fields accordingly.

Comment: but I need to show terms as a list.. when I will use expose filter then it will not shown as a list like above image.. can is it possible?

Comment: Try to use Select with Style module. Hope it will fix your requirement.